# How to get starting date and end date of year in Android?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I need help in getting start and end date of **current year, last year and next year**.

Below is  my code: this code is work fine for month, can I modify it for year?

Note: this code is only for example.

```
   protected void getDataByMonths(int currentDayOfMonth) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        int month;

        if (currentDayOfMonth >= 2) {

            month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        } else {

            month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - currentDayOfMonth;
        }
        int day = 1;

        calendar.set(year, month, day);

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        int numOfDaysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        String firstday = String.valueOf(df.format(calendar.getTime()));

        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numOfDaysInMonth - 1);

        String lastday = String.valueOf(df.format(calendar.getTime()));


        String result = getButtonName(button) + " From :" + getDateInMonthFormat(firstday) + " " + "To :" + getDateInMonthFormat(lastday);

        finalcontacts = mySqliteDBhelper.getContactsBetweenRange(button, getDateInMilliseconds(firstday),  getDateInMilliseconds(lastday));

        finalstatus.setText(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
public static String GetYearSlot(int option,String inputDate)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy",java.util.Locale.getDefault());
        Date myDate = null;
        try
        {
            myDate = sdf.parse(inputDate);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(myDate);

        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, option);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        Date YearFirstDay = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
        Date YearLastDay = calendar.getTime();

        return sdf.format(YearFirstDay)+"-"+sdf.format(YearLastDay);
    }
```

how to use:

GetYearSlot(1, fromDate): it gives you next year from the date you passed(input 1)

GetYearSlot(0, fromDate): it gives you current year from the date you passed(input 0)

GetYearSlot(-1, fromDate): it gives you previous year from the date you passed(input -1)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you cannot use `Java 8`, here is how it could be done:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

// Create first day of year
Calendar firstDayOfCurrentYear = Calendar.getInstance();
firstDayOfCurrentYear.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
firstDayOfCurrentYear.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
System.out.println(df.format(firstDayOfCurrentYear.getTime()));

// Create last day of year
Calendar lastDayOfCurrentYear = Calendar.getInstance();
lastDayOfCurrentYear.set(Calendar.DATE, 31);
lastDayOfCurrentYear.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
System.out.println(df.format(lastDayOfCurrentYear.getTime()));

// Create first day of next year
Calendar firstDayOfNextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
firstDayOfNextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
firstDayOfNextYear.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
firstDayOfNextYear.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
System.out.println(df.format(firstDayOfNextYear.getTime()));

// Create last day of next year
Calendar lastDayOfNextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
lastDayOfNextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
lastDayOfNextYear.set(Calendar.DATE, 31);
lastDayOfNextYear.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
System.out.println(df.format(lastDayOfNextYear.getTime()));
```

**Output:**

```
01/01/2016
12/31/2016
01/01/2017
12/31/2017
```

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

First get the current date.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “America/Montreal” );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Use `Year` to represent the entire year as an object.

```
Year thisYear = Year.from( today );
Year nextYear = thisYear.plusYears( 1 );
Year lastYear = thisYear.minusYears( 1 );
```

Usually in date-time work we represent a span of time using the Half-Open approach. In this approach the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a year would start on January first and run up to, but not include, January 1 of the following year.

If on Java 8, you could include the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project and its [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class to represent the span of time.

Otherwise do it yourself.

```
LocalDate thisYearStart = thisYear.atDay( 1 );
LocalDate lastYearStart = lastYear.atDay( 1 );
LocalDate nextYearStart = nextYear.atDay( 1 );
```

If you truly need the last day of the year, you could just subtract one day from the first day of the following year. Even easier is using a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) defined in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class.

```
LocalDate thisYearFirstDay = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear() );
LocalDate thisYearLastDay = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear() );

LocalDate nextYearFirstDay = thisYearLastDay.plusDays( 1 );
LocalDate nextYearLastDay = nextYearFirstDay.with( TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear() );

LocalDate lastYearLastDay = thisYearFirstDay.minusDays( 1 );
LocalDate lastYearFirstDay = lastYearLastDay.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear() );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).